# Detect camera shift or rotation using a reference image captured from the camera

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Need to find if the camera is shifted or not by comparing  with a refernece image. Please check the images for my need.

- In the first image no shift is detected but an additional object is added in the camera frame.
- In the other cases camera is shifted to some angle.

In the minimal case need to detect camera is shifted or not and in a better case, need to get the shift angle. Can anybody have a solution for this?
[image: Shift_comparison]

Comment: it's not clear what you want. do you want to automate this? should it only work with this scene or any scene? from the information you provided I'd say what's your problem, you already know which images are shifted/rotated. task complete. this post is very unlikely to become on-topic. please read [ask]

Comment: The actual scenario is in outside. A CC camera used for intruder detection. If anyone changes the current camera position, need to understand the shift has occurred. This may be a large shift(camera tampering condition) or maybe a small shift(below 90 degrees).